# How to choose multisite instance inside script running from main Drupal directory?

Tags: 7, multi-sites

As in question. I know that I can use drush command, but I have small script and I don't want to create module from it. Now I calling that script inside main Drupal folder (no multisites).

Inside that script I just bootstraping Drupal (I need Access to Drupal API):

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
#db integration
```

(The same PHP header I use for e.g unit tests class)

It is possible to run such script in multisite enviromnent too?

My problem is that every sites config settings.php has db name called 'default'. So I don't know how to use [db_set_active](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7) properly.

I have script that creating data  (txt file) for [Menu Import](https://drupal.org/project/menu_import) module. I need access to Drupal and Joomla db, because I need to migrate menu from Joomla.

Anyway [here](http://pastebin.com/1b7VvA0u) is a script

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? Are you going to manipulate data in the database? Have you separate databases for each site? Please note that `DRUPAL_ROOT` is probably not set yet, unless you have included a file above that row.

Comment: Manipulating data. I have migrating script that uses Batch API. It slow, very slow. I would to use console, but I don't know want to rewrite it for using Drush. DRUPAL_ROOT is set. I edited my code.

Comment: Then to answer your question, yes, you can run such script in a multisite environment. I don't know how the Batch API looks like, but depending on the number of databases you have, you'll wan't to take a few at a time. You would also have to specify which databases to connect to. Do you have a known list or do you know if every database at the server should be modified? If you have a known pattern for the drupal databases' names then you could use something like `SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%drupal%'` to get the relevant ones.

Comment: Yes I know db to modify. it's single db, but I must avoid to modify or others dbs.

Comment: Then just connect to that one. I can't really understand what your problem is? Is there something that doesn't work?

Comment: so do you think that using db_set_active is all I need?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Is this something that will run on a schedule or just once? Can you tell us anything more about what data you want to manipulate and how you want to manipulate it?

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the database name, you can dynamically set a database name which you will call with `db_set_active()`.

This is copy/pasted from the link below.

```
  $other_database = array(
      'database' => 'databasename',
      'username' => 'username', // assuming this is necessary
      'password' => 'password', // assuming this is necessary
      'host' => 'localhost', // assumes localhost
      'driver' => 'mysql', // replace with your database driver
  );
  // replace 'YourDatabaseKey' with something that's unique to your module
  Database::addConnectionInfo('YourDatabaseKey', 'default', $other_database);
  db_set_active('YourDatabaseKey');

  // execute queries here

  db_set_active(); // without the paramater means set back to the default for the site
  drupal_set_message(t('The queries have been made.'));
```

More about this can be found [here](http://drupal.org/node/18429).